# FontAwesome icons not displaying

Tags: 2013, css, design, cssregistration, file-icons

Am using Font Awesome search icon on the web site using the icons at the local level as shown below, but it does not appear when. How do I solve it?

The link to the Awesome Font style:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration" Name="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />`
```

[image]

I put this as the CSS script:

```
.ms-srch-sb-searchLink:before { 
  content: "\f002";  /* Icon font - magnifying glass*/
  font-family: FontAwesome;  /* Font face */
  color: #CF9223;  /* Font color */
  font-size: 19px;  /* Icon size */
  padding: 0 0 0 7px;  /* Space between text and container edges */
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the font at the top of your CSS file:

```
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

*The lastest version of the Font Awesome you can check here 
http://fontawesome.io/get-started/*