# sharepoint quick launch customization appearence

Tags: sharepoint-server

i want to insert image in quicklaunch sharepoint , for each link in quick launch we need to give small image before the name[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to custom code using `JQuery` such that Icons (`<img>` incase of image icons or `classes` in case of plugins like *glyphicons*) gets dynamically injected to the quick launch in html, just before the menu items.

Another option is to overwrite the default CSS of the quick launch to include custom icons

Here is a [disscusion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122597/adding-font-awesome-icons-to-quick-launch-links) that should give you a good Idea

Other Sources :

[Customizing Quick Launch with JQuery and CSS](http://bangimportant.itgroove.net/2015/07/24/3-ways-to-improve-sharepoint-quick-launch-style/)

[Customizing with CSS](http://kamalasekar.blogspot.in/2012/01/add-bullet-to-sharepoint-quick-launch.html)